# Display error message in a correct way if username already exists in a registration webform (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, registration

I am able to check if username already exists using a code like this:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Job_Registration_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        String checkUsr_query = "SELECT count(*) from Job_UserData where username = @Usn";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(checkUsr_query, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usn", TextBox_Usn.Text);
        if (!comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Equals("0"))
        {
            Label_Usn.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Label_Usn.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception check_usr)
    {
        Response.Write(check_usr.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Other variations don't use a separate label, instead they change the text in `RequiredFieldValidator` or I can use it with `CustomValidator` and changing its visibility.
**What I want to do is** check if textboxes are empty when submit button is pressed which is taken care by `RequiredFieldValidator` and as soon as I leave the Username textbox it should check and display whether the username is available or not and the *Submit* click should not allow the user to register.

Currently I am using this code:

```
 protected void Button_RegForm_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /*  if (Label_Usn.Visible)
    {
        return;
    }
   * */
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Job_Registration_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        String insert_query = "INSERT into Job_UserData VALUES (@Usn,@Pass,@Village,@Contact,@Address,@Occupation)";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insert_query, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usn", TextBox_Usn.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", TextBox_Pass.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Village", TextBox_Village.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", TextBox_Contact.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox_Address.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", TextBox_Occupation.Text);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception insertError)
    {
        Response.Write(insertError.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Job_Registration_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        String checkUsr_query = "SELECT count(*) from Job_UserData where username = @Usn";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(checkUsr_query, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usn", TextBox_Usn.Text);
        if (!comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Equals("0"))
        { 
            args.IsValid = false;

        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception check_usr)
    {
        Response.Write(check_usr.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

And I have to use `AutoPostBack` for Username textbox to make sure that Duplicate username is checked as soon as I get out of the Username textbox. The code I posted works without `AutoPostBack` but it lets user to register even after displaying that username is not available and it doesn't check for duplicate username without clicking the *Submit* button.

When I am using `AutoPostBack` property it created problem with the `RequiredFieldValidator` property as if the field is empty the page refreshes due to `PostBack` after I leave the username textbox and the "Username is required" message flashes for a second and then disappears which I don't want.
I tried putting the username checking part in `Page_Load` method and used text change property for `RequiredFieldValidator`, but sometimes it displays wrong message.

How can I accomplish this or is it done using `Page_load` method but I am doing it wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?
The way I want this form to work is how I believe other online forms work, if they work differently please share that method.

Comment: As a side question, are you really sending queries to your server every single time the client-side validation occurs? I'd check if the username exists only on submit.

Comment: I thought that usually the forms tell you that username is available as soon as you type it and change the textbox

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal, for that he needs cookies to be enabled .., Am i right ?

Comment: @goofyui , no idea about that so I think yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another example:

```
protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckLogin(txtLogin.Text.ToString().Trim()))
    {
        //Register the user
    }
    else
    {
        lblLoginAvailable.Visible = true;
        lblLoginAvailable.Text = "This login already exists in our system. Chooce another login please";
    }
}

protected bool CheckLogin(string login)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from users where lower(login) = lower(@login)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;
    string id = "";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        id = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "" : cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

I use this in my project and it works for 100%. Hope this code make your understanding clear and will help you.

Comment: After the "user already exits" label's visibility is set true the message will stay there even if the next username  typed does not already   exists in the database,can I do something about it?I know that i may have to set its visibility to false again but I am not sure at which point

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal change this method to that: 
protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblLoginAvailable.Visible = false; //every time, when user clicks on button, it will hire your control first, and then do next steps
    if (!CheckLogin(txtLogin.Text.ToString().Trim()))
    {
        //Register the user
    }
    else
    {
        lblLoginAvailable.Visible = true;
        lblLoginAvailable.Text = "This login already exists in our system. Chooce another login please";
    }
}

Comment: everything works well except one , when I type in a username change the textbox then come back to username textbox and delete this username and change textbox again ,"username is required" flashes and then goes away.I know its related to autopostpack and requiredfieldvalidator but its is very annoying ,is there a work around for that so that either that mesaage is not shown or it stays there?

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal delete custom validator

Answer (score 0):

Your TextBox Control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtUserName_TextChanged" />
```

Your *txtUserName_TextChanged* method:

```
protected void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your_con_string_name"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from Job_UserData where lower(username) = lower(@Usn)", con);
    //your code will not work, if you have in database UserName = "login", but user write it as "Login", because your sql-query is case sensitive
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usn", txtUserName.Text);
    bool is_exists = false;
    try{
        con.Open();
        is_exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? false : true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //if you will work with exceptions. But they will not be =)
    }
    finally{
        con.Close();
    }
    if (is_exists)
    {
        someLabelBelowTheTextBox.Text = "This UserName is already exists. Please Choose another one";
        txtUserName.Focus();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you in your case.

Comment: What does Focus do and it will still register if username already exists and I press the submit button unless I have missed something here

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal Focus will move cursor automatically to your control and it will take controlling. I'm sure that this code works, definitely I'm. But may be in your case TextChanged method works not as expected. So try to move code inside TextChanged to Button_Click method to check that. I will provide you one more answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" required />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" required />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvUsername" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
    SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Username already existing!" Display="Dynamic"
    OnServerValidate="cvUsername_ServerValidate" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="btnSignUp_Click" />
```

To lessen the hassle of adding a RequiredFieldValidator control, you can use the HTML required attribute instead.

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void cvUsername_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Job_Registration_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Job_UserData WHERE Username=@Username";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
    SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (data.HasRows) // Username is existing
        args.IsValid = true; // will display error message
    else
        args.IsValid = false;
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```